# php - count() by key in second array of multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following array

```
$_POST[0][name]
$_POST[0][type]
$_POST[0][planet]
...
$_POST[1][name]
$_POST[1][type]
$_POST[1][planet]
```

**Now i want to count all the $_POST[x][type]. How to do that?**

(**If i would reverse** the multidimensional array, it would work i guess like this:)

```
$count = count($_POST['type']);
```

how can i count the "type" in the original structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$type_count = 0;
foreach($arr as $v) {
    if(array_key_exists('type', $v)) $type_count++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, this works:

```
$count = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $_POST);

echo count($count['name']); # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($_POST as $value) {
   if (isset($value['type']) {
      $count++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP5.3 style

```
$count = array_reduce (
    $_POST,
    function ($sum, $current) {
        return $sum + ((int) array_key_exists('type', $current));
    },
    0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

And using set operations:

```
$key = 'type';
$tmp = array_map($_POST, function($val) use ($key) {return isset($val[$key]);});
$count = array_reduce($tmp, function($a, $b) { return $a + $b; }, 0);
```

So you could reduce that down an array_filter:

```
$key = 'type';
$count = count(array_filter($_POST, function($val) use ($key) { return isset($val[$key]);}));
```